How can I prevent running out of ports?
sorry if the Title is misleadling I didn't know how to ask it properly. I'll explain my situation as much as I can.
I have a go-gin web server running. Lately it get's stuck. Not responding to requests anymore and I don't have a timeout logic(which might be my problem) therefore I'm waiting the request response forever. The machine is windows, I was checking resource monitor and task manager in case of leak, which was not the case. Once the web server got frozen(not responding to requests anymore) I used netstat command to see the open connections and found out there was tons of :3306 in state of TIME_WAIT like 80ish or something. I think this is causing my web server to not respond new request's anymore. When I checked console output I saw the requests that can come in was actually getting response in 2-40ish ms. which is normal.
TL;DR
I think my database connection is not correct, it's not getting closed properly and causing to run out of ports.
I'll share my code below, can someone point me which part might be causing this issue?
//main.go
func createDBPool(connectionString string, maxConnections int) (*sql.DB, error) {
    db, err := sql.Open("mysql", connectionString)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    db.SetMaxOpenConns(maxConnections) // Set the maximum number of open connections
    return db, nil
}

func main() {
// Initialize database connection => field GlobalDBPool *sql.DB
//config.GlobalDbCon => "dbusername:dbuserpassword@tcp(dbip:dbport)/databasename
config.GlobalDBPool, err = createDBPool(config.GlobalDbCon, 30)
    if err != nil {
        sC.Logger.Error("Couldn't initialize database connection to global database.", "Error", err)
        os.Exit(1)
    }
    defer config.GlobalDBPool.Close()
//..Some other initialization codes are here
//This is how I distribute my config which contains database connection and other stuff
RSSServices := sC.RSSServices{ServerConfig: config}
userService := sC.UserService{ServerConfig: config}
subService := sC.SubscriptionService{ServerConfig: config}

//Again some code here and then routes come in place
r.GET("/some-endpoint", userService.SomeEndPointGET())
r.POST("/another-endpoint", subService.AnotherEndpointPOST())
err = r.Run(":80")
if err != nil {
        sC.Logger.Error("Server couldn't be initialized.", "Error", err)
        os.Exit(3)
    }
}

This is how I use the connection. I've checked all my functions and they are all same/similar
//SubscriptionService.go
type UserService struct {
    ServerConfig *models.Config
}

func (us *UserService) AnotherEndpointPOST() func(c *gin.Context) {
    sqlStatement := `PLACEHOLDER-SQL-STATEMENT-FOR-PRIVACY`

    err := us.ServerConfig.GlobalDBPool.QueryRow(sqlStatement, "param1").Scan(&var1, &var2, &var3)
    if err != nil {
        c.JSON(400, gin.H{"code": "some-error-code-string"})
            return
    }

    outputVar := fmt.Sprintf("\\\\%s\\%s\\%s", var1, var2, var3)

    c.JSON(200, gin.H{"code": "outputVar"})
}

I had to replace my sql and some variables. But in general this is how I use the database connection in every endpoint. I don't manually close or dispose anything which I think is wrong. Can someone point me if this approach is correct or should I close the connections? I use the "database/sql" library in my code.

what is the dbConn in dbConn.QueryRow? How do you get it?

How many is that tons of connection to mysql? Your code creates a connection pool, so there is got to be more than one connections to mysql for sure.

@Shadow they seem to be saying the connections are to their webserver, not mysql. not clear mysql is at all involved in this.

We <ould need a more complete chunk of code to understand what is going on. For example: if I read your current snippet, the main() function calls createDBPool() and exists right away, the other things your mention (named xxxService) are initialized outside of the main function,and no code shows how the fields in config are used in your code (do you use config.GlobalDBPool ? or config.GlobalDBCon ? or something else ? ...)

dbConn.QueryRow - please check for any calls to dbConn.Query. You don't need to close anything with QueryRow, but do with other functions such as Query (failure to call rows.Close() could well cause the issue you are seeing). Really need an MRE to help further.

@LeGEC I've updated the code, added the connection func that I was using in main.go and specified what my database connection looks like. Basically I initialize my database connections and then just re use them without closing in my endpoints. However as @Brits mentioned I can't share whole code because it has almost 30 endpoints and a lot of code, I'm not sure which part might cause so I just gave 1 example of how I use database. I noticed that I use query methods in some places and don't close them with rows.Close() call so I'll check on this. In which document can I check this further?

"don't close them with rows.Close()" - the usage example is probably a good place to start, there is also a tutorial and quite a few questions here. If close is not called (and you don't process the full result set) then a connection is leaked.
